# Cannot install remix-ide locally

Tags: remix

How to install remix-ide npm module? I follow the instructions, but it does not install.

```
npm install remix-ide -g
...

make: *** [Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/remix-ide/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: Fix for me was using node -v 10.x.x, which if you use nvm , then swap is easy between versions i,e: `nvm use v10.16.0`. This did not require any additional installations as node-gyp.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s a `node-gyp` package issue.
Here are some commands to try to install this package.

If you use windows try :

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
```

And for Ubuntu/Mac users, try :

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```